# Inconsistent visuals between Material view and Rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Edit: Cant seem to set my answer as the answer yet so check my own answer for details on how I fixed this.

Im fairly new to Blender and Im trying to set up a material that can import textures and models from a game I need and edit with them in blender. (not edit them)

It has a lot of color lookup style stuff this "CC" texture but for some reason Im getting inconsistent visuals between the rendered version and material view.

[image: Material view and Render view are different]
The main question Im asking is... Should I make sure certain things connect correctly? (like yellow point to yellow, ect)
Or would having the color I end up with from a color ramp linking into a mix then going to a Diffuse BSDF then Output end up rendering just fine?

Here is a version I have currently, its in the end meant to apply a "base gradient", "Pattern Gradient", "Pattern" and "Sticker" to a part in that order (so a sticker covers the pattern and the pattern covers the base gradient).
(Details on what everything there means is documented on this guide here: https://www.overkillsoftware.com/workshopmanual/ )

[image: somewhat working version]

Thank you for any help and tips!

Comment: "*Should I make sure certain things connect correctly?*" Definitely. Some can be overlooked like Value and Colors or Colors and Vector. Also Material shading mode is meant as a reference, or helping guide, not a full blown material preview, inconsistencies are to be expected

Comment: The problem you are having is unclear: is it about "Inconsistent visuals between Material view and Rendered" or about "Should I make sure certain things connect correctly" ? In the first case, what is the problem faced, which is also unclear from the screenshots. Can you split your problems in two distinct questions? That would help the reader address them and increase the chance of resolution.

Comment: Thank you Duarte for the comment, Ill double check everything and see if its linked.

Comment: Bruno, its a bit of both I still think, sorry Im not too good at explaining what Im asking but the issue I was having was if connections I had was messing with the rendered/material views, and this might be the case but Im still yet to check everything

Comment: Got it. Think of updating (edit link) your question once fleshed out. This will help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have solved my own answer.

From what I understand I linked 2 Color ramps to different Fac areas relating to my "sticker" and its gloss causing a white fill effect in material view while not showing in rendered.

I guess the moral of the story is make sure everything links to the right place.

Thank you Duarte for the comment telling me to check if the right node types are connected.